# prefix expression to evaluate with (min,max) variable range

Tags: dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I tried to solve the below quiz question but could to not get 100% accepted result and few tests were still failing. Any better approach?
Problem statement:
Evaluates the prefix expression and calculate the maximum result for the given variable ranges.

Arguments:
expression: the prefix expression to evaluate.
variables: Keys of this dictionary may appear as variables in the expression.
Values are tuples of `(min, max)` that specify the range of values of the variable.
The upper bound `max` is NOT included in the range, so (2, 5) expands to [2, 3, 4].
Returns:
int: the maximum result of the expression for any combination of the supplied variables.
None: in the case there is no valid result for any combination of the supplied variables.

Mycode

```
#!/bin/python3
import os
import sys


from typing import Dict, Optional, Tuple

# Complete the max_result_expression function below.
# You may add any imports you require from the standard library.
# Feel free to define your own helper functions, classes etc as you see fit.

def max_result_expression(expression: str, variables: Dict[str, Tuple[int, int]]) -> Optional[int]:
    """
    Evaluates the prefix expression and calculate the maximum result for the given variable ranges.
    
    
    Arguments:
    expression: the prefix expression to evaluate.
    variables: Keys of this dictionary may appear as variables in the expression.
    Values are tuples of `(min, max)` that specify the range of values of the variable.
    The upper bound `max` is NOT included in the range, so (2, 5) expands to [2, 3, 4].
    Returns:
    int: the maximum result of the expression for any combination of the supplied variables.
    None: in the case there is no valid result for any combination of the supplied variables.
    """
    
    
    tokens = expression.split()
    N = len(tokens)
    if '0' in tokens:
        return None
    
    
    # check if there is only single token in expression
    # and it is integer
    if N == 1:
        if isinstance(variables.get(tokens[0]), tuple):
            pair = variables.get(tokens[0])
            return max(range(pair[0], pair[1]))
        elif tokens[0].isdigit():
            return tokens[0]
        else:
            return None
    elif N == 2:
        return None
    
    
    stack = []
    # traverse the tokens from the end
    for t in reversed(tokens):
        # added try block to handle if experession does not have invalid tokens
        try:
            # handle if operator is '+'
            if t == '+':
                if isinstance(stack[-2], tuple):
                    stack[-2] = max(stack[-2])-1
                if isinstance(stack[-1],tuple):
                    stack[-1] = max(stack[-1])-1
                    stack[-2:] = [stack[-1] + stack[-2]]
            # handle if operator is '-'
            elif t == '-':
                if isinstance(stack[-2], tuple):
                    stack[-2] = min(stack[-2])
                if isinstance(stack[-1], tuple):
                    stack[-1] = max(stack[-1])-1
                    stack[-2:] = [stack[-1] - stack[-2]]
            # handle if operator is '*'
            elif t == '*':
                if isinstance(stack[-2], tuple):
                    stack[-2] = max(stack[-2])-1
                if isinstance(stack[-1], tuple):
                    stack[-1] = max(stack[-1])-1
                    stack[-2:] = [stack[-1] * stack[-2]]
            # handle if operator is '*'
            elif t == '/':
                if isinstance(stack[-2], tuple):
                    stack[-2] = min(stack[-2])
                if isinstance(stack[-1], tuple):
                    stack[-1] = max(stack[-1])-1
                    stack[-2:] = [stack[-1] // stack[-2]]
            else:
                if not t.isdigit():
                    stack.append(variables[t])
                else:
                    # ignore if token is octal or negative
                    if len(t)>1 and t[0] == '0' or t[0] == '-' or t[0] == '+':
                    return None
    
            # ignore if token is hexadecimal
            if len(t) > 2 and t[0:2] == '0x':
                 return None
            stack.append(int(t))
    
    
        except:
        # handle if token is non digit and not operator
            return None

    if len(stack) > 1:
        return None
    return stack[0]




#print(max_result_expression('* - 2 x y', {"x": (0,2), "y": (2,4)}))
#print(max_result_expression('* - 2 x y', {"x": (-2,0), "y": (-4,0)}))
#print(max_result_expression('+ 1 0', {}))


# print(max_result_expression('+ 6 * - 4 + 2 3 8', {}))
# print(max_result_expression('x', {"x":(1,5)}))
expression= '- 1 / 100 - 5 a'


variables= {'a': (1, 10)}
print(max_result_expression(expression, variables))


# expression: * - + - a b c + d 1 + + 2 e - + f f + e 10


# variables: {'a': (0, 3), 'b': (3, 6), 'c': (4, 8), 'd': (0, 10), 'e': (2, 3), 'f': (23, 28)}
```

Comment: Can you share a failing test-case, i.e. a set of input, expected output and actual output? Also, is there any particular reason you tagged this with 'dynamic programming' and 'knapsack problem'? There's no obvious reference to either one in your post or code.

Comment: I thought a better way to solve this via DP. It was the part of the Interview and 28/32, that was the score of this solution.